# Does it make sense to combine my final program into a single C file to save memory?

Tags: c, memory

I understand that it's good practice to split up a C program into multiple .h and .c files, but since each .h file has an `#ifndef #define #endif` "include guard", don't all those defined constants take up memory in my final program?  If I'm **really** trying to be conservative with memory usage, would combining my final program into one large C file to get rid of all the "include guards" help?

Comment: Those are not constants, but preprocessor directives for the compiler. No memory use involved.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The include guards are not part of the content of the final program (of the object modules produced by the compiler or of the executable file produced by the linker). The include guards are instructions to the compiler during compilation; they do not contribute data to the final program file.

Constants defined with `#define` also do not appear as data in the final program.

It is possible that some objects define in headers may result in multiple objects being defined in the final program. For example, `static int x = 3;` could result in multiple occurrences of this `x` appearing in the final program. Generally, headers should avoid defining objects; they should only declare identifiers for objects that are defined in source files.

Answer (score 0):

Preprocessor macros don't normally use any additional memory or storage, so reducing the use of these things is probably not be a good reason to combine multiple source files together.

However, there might be other good reasons to do so, in large projects. For example, the maintainers of SQLite3 claim (see
https://www.sqlite.org/amalgamation.html) that merging all the sources together leads to 5-10% faster execution. Presumably this is because it allows for better compiler optimization.

However, it's very difficult to maintain vast C source files, and they take an age to compile.